# Set Letter Spacing for each character Html Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, web

I want to set letter-spacing for each character with different size when user typing in text box. I tried to use letter-spacing in css but it changed all characters with same size. is it possible way to do that?

here my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0' />
    <style>.pr { letter-spacing: 10px; }</style>
    </head>
     <body>
       <div id='editor' contenteditable='true' style='white-space: pre-line;'><pr></pr>
       </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If we'll forget Shaheryar's answer, the only way is to create an element (ex. `span`) for every character, and then use CSS to set left/right padding of the spans.

Comment: @Teemu how to set when user typing?

Comment: That's too broad to answer without some code of your own. In general, listen `keydown` on the editor (`input` might do too), and override the default action. Use either [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) or [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to insert a new span.

Comment: @Teemu please give me a demo, I'm just beginner just acrossing web language

Comment: Creating such a functionality is not a trivial task when done properly, it's a quite a big job. You've to start implementing the feature with the given advices, and then if you get stcuk, ask a question about the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

use `&nbsp;` for extra spaces between tags in HTML.

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: This is an awful solution, but it works, it's a bit rough, though.

Comment: I don't understand. When user typing how to set it.